# Three.js & OrbitControls.js - Can I change the input configuration?

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a simple Three.js demo that uses OrbitControls.js. Currently, the left mouse button orbits, the right mouse button pans, and the middle mouse button/scroll wheel dollies (zooms). But I'd like to swap orbit and pan so that they are controlled by the right mouse button and left mouse button, respectively. Are there configuration settings to change this functionality? Or will I have to dive into the code to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By now you can Configure the Mouse-Controls very easily. Just get the Control-Object and then change the Mouse-Button Configuration like this:

```
this._controls = new OrbitControls(world._engine._camera, world._container);
// Mouse buttons
this._controls.mouseButtons = { ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT, ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, PAN: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT };
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to dive into the code; there's no configuration option at the moment. Happily it's a pretty easy change; you just need to update the `onMouseDown` function and change the conditional that checks `event.button`:

```
// you could change this to `event.button == 1` if you wanted the 
/// right mouse button to rotate, and so on...
if ( event.button === 0 ) {
    if ( scope.noRotate === true ) return;

    state = STATE.ROTATE;

    rotateStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

} else if ( event.button === 1 ) {
    if ( scope.noZoom === true ) return;

    state = STATE.DOLLY;

    dollyStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

} else if ( event.button === 2 ) {
    if ( scope.noPan === true ) return;

    state = STATE.PAN;

    panStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

}
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L333-L352

One of the reasons these controls are put in examples (rather than part of the core) is that folks' needs vary pretty widely, so you're encouraged to edit the controls to suit your needs.

three.js r68

Comment: I came up with a configurable solution to this problem based on your suggestion. The mouse button layout is just another member variable of the ObjectControls class, which you can change after instantiating it. Is this an addition worth proposing to the maintainers of the code?

Comment: Hm, apparently such a change has been merged already for the next version! https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5260

Answer (score 2):

As of Three.js r99 you can switch orbit controls mouse buttons like this:

```
controls.mouseButtons = {
    LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE,
    RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT
}
```

See https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls

Answer (score 0):

In the latest update of three.js(r131), you can try this

controls.mouseButtons = {LEFT: 0, MIDDLE: 1, RIGHT: 2};

Where, 0 = orbit, 1 = zoom and 2 = pan contol